Lower bound on the norm of product of 2 matrices
I've recently been reading Matrix Perturbation Theory by Stewart and Sun 1. I am confused about Theorem 3.9: for any unitarily invariant norm $\|\cdot\|$, one has $\|AB\|\geq \|A\|\inf_2(B)$. The proof is omitted and the authors claimed it is just a corollary of Execise 1.4.6.
However, I believe there may be an issue with this assertion. Below is a counterexample I've considered

$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&3},B=\pmatrix{1\\0}$, then $AB=\pmatrix{1\\0}$. However, now we have $\|AB\|=1,\|A\|=3,\inf_2(B)=1$, a contradiction!

I attempted to solve Exercise 1.4.6, but I don't understand why in the hint it states that, without loss of generality, we can assume $A $ is a nonsingular matrix.
The following assertion is made in Exercise 1.4.6:
Let $ B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n} $ have singular values $ \sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \dots \geq \sigma_n $, and let $ C = AB $ have singular values $ \tau_1 \geq \tau_2 \geq \dots \geq \tau_n $. Then, it asserts that $ \tau_i \geq \sigma_i \inf_2(A) $ for $ i = 1, \dots, n $.(Hint: Assume without loss of generality that $A$ is squared and nonsingular)
The book defines $ \inf_2(A) $ as follows: For $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$, if $n\geq k$, then $\inf_2(A) = \min_{\|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_2 $.
I would like to figure out where exactly the issue lies—whether it’s a misunderstanding on my part of the book’s meaning or something else. Thank you very much.

Seems to me like the author simply made an error. Equation 3.9 in the theorem is correct and actually follows from Exercise 1.4.6, but Equation 3.8, the one you're asking this question about, is simply wrong, and your counterexample seems correct to me.

OK, finally I have solved this problem and I think the issue lies in $\text{inf}_2(B)\neq\text{inf}_2(B^T)$.
Here is my proof of Exercise 1.4.6.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times m}$. If $\text{rank}(A) < m$, then it follows that $\text{inf}_2(A) = 0$, and the inequalities are trivial.
Otherwise, suppose $A$ is column full-rank, implying $\text{rank}(A) = m$. In this case, it holds that $\text{rank}(B) = \text{rank}(AB)$, leading to the conclusion that if $\tau_i = 0$, then $\sigma_i = 0$. Therefore, we can restrict our attention to the non-zero singular values of $AB$.
Since $A$ is column full-rank, we have $A^T A > 0$, which allows us to write $A^T A = \Gamma^2$ for some positive definite matrix $\Gamma$. Consequently, $AB$ can be rewritten as $AB = A\Gamma^{-1} \Gamma B$. Given that $A\Gamma^{-1}$ is column orthogonal, the non-zero singular values of $AB$ are precisely those of $\Gamma B$.
Since $\Gamma$ is a square, non-singular matrix, we can apply Theorem 4.5 from the book to the matrix product $\Gamma^{-1} \cdot \Gamma B$. Combining this with the identity $$\|\Gamma^{-1}\|^{-1}=\text{inf}_2(\Gamma)=\min_{\|x\|=1}x^T\Gamma^T\Gamma x=\min_{\|x\|=1}x^T\Gamma^T\Gamma^{-1}A^TA\Gamma^{-1}\Gamma x=\min_{\|x\|=1}x^TA^TAx=\text{inf}_2(A),$$ the proof is completed.

From the exercise, it follows that: $ \|AB\| \geq \text{inf}_2(A)\|B\| \quad \text{and} \quad \|AB\| = \|B^T A^T\| \geq \text{inf}_2(B^T)\|A^T\| = \text{inf}_2(B^T)\|A\|$.
However, since $\text{inf}_2(B) \neq \text{inf}_2(B^T)$ (as demonstrated by my counterexample above where $\text{inf}_2(B) = 1$ while $\text{inf}_2(B^T) = 0$), we cannot conclude that $\|AB\| \geq \|A\|\text{inf}_2(B)$.
